# Xamarin Android: Unable to instantiate receiver (BOOT_COMPLETED)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to add a `BroadcastReceiver` to a `Xamarin.Forms` project on `Android`. This receiver shall be started every time, the device is booted. I added this `C#` code:

```
namespace SMSIP2.Droid
{
    [BroadcastReceiver]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionBootCompleted })]
    class BootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public BootReceiver()
        {

        }
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(context, "Received intent!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
    }

}
```

and modified by `AndroidManifest.xml` so, that it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.companyname.SMSIP2" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <application android:label="SMSIP2.Android"></application>
</manifest>
```

Now, when I restart the device (or trigger the receiver by broadcasting a `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` message) I get this error message:

```
Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver md5b010e9266249275df36d0fbfd645bb11.BootReceiver: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "md5b010e9266249275df36d0fbfd645bb11.BootReceiver" on path:
DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.companyname.SMSIP2-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.companyname.SMSIP2-1/lib/x86_64, /data/app/com.companyname.SMSIP2-1/base.apk!/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
```

To be honest, I do not really understand why this error is raised, as I followed typical instructions (as for example [these](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/80876/open-an-app-on-startup-after-booting-not-working)).

Comment: Can you attach your `classes.dex` from your `obj/{configuration}/android/bin` folder?

Comment: @JonDouglas That was a great idea! Somehow, my new class was not added into the classes.dex file, somehow. After I deleted the `obj` folder and built the solution again, everything is working now again. So I guess, this is some `xamarin` bug, isn't it?

Comment: Sadly yes. It's one I've been trying to track down the cause of. Do you perhaps have incremental assembly versions enabled? See this bug: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=61073#c25